# Linux - WiFi router randomly disconnects, does the WiFi card's Tx-Power being below the Signal level mean that the connection is unstable?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

TL;DR: My Wi-Fi connection dies a few times a day, Restarting PC/router does nothing 70% of the time. Sometimes it comes back if I wait long enough. `iwconfig` says that Tx-Power < abs(Signal level). Does this mean my PC can only hear my router, not say anything to it? If so, how fix?

I switched to using Linux Mint a few weeks back and it's going quite nicely, but I have this issue where I just randomly get disconnected from my router. The router shows up in the network manager applet and sometimes just turning Wi-Fi off and on again works, but most of the time I'm left wondering why it just won't connect. I know that the router is working normally, because my phone is having no problem connecting to the same router. The computer also sometimes randomly reconnects if I leave it for a while, I have no idea why that is.

I started looking around for potential causes, trying out the unfamiliar `iwconfig`s and `sudo`s. I've tried restarting the router and my computer multiple times when I urgently needed the Wi-Fi, and I've also tried setting the connection to 2.4GHz because there is a wall between me and the router most of the time. Sometimes it'll work and my Wi-Fi connection comes back, but then a hour or two later it dies again. I reverted the 2.4GHz restriction after seeing it did not help.

A few days ago I found this strange setting in the network connections manager that said "Transmission power", but I didn't know what it did. Then I ran `iwconfig` again (I'd gained some knowledge of the commands after fiddling with them so much) and saw that Tx-Power was WAY lower than abs(Signal level). I'd read somewhere that there can be situations where the computer can hear the router but can't talk to it because its signal isn't good enough, so I thought my Tx was going below 0dBm during transmission and was just dying before reaching the router. Is this what's happening with my computer? If so, how can I bump up the Tx-Power to be above abs(Signal level)?

Comment: Look at `man iwconfig`, specifically `iwconfig <dev> power saving <setting>`